# Is it possible to change my web application server date using Robot Framework & RIDE?

Tags: python-2.7, testing, automation, robotframework

I am currently testing a web application & for some reason in the application business I need to change the db server & application server date so that some of the disabled fields in the web application become enabled for editing, so is there any possible way to automate the part of changing the servers date to a certain date using Robot Framework & it IDE (RIDE) ?

and if it is possible please provide any code sample as an example...

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible, though that depends on whether or not your server and database allow you to change the date while its running. There's nothing built-in to robot to do this, but if you can create a program or script that does this, you can use the [Process library](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Process.html) to run that script.

In other words, the limiting factor isn't robot framework, it's your system. If your system allows you to do this at runtime, you can certainly do it from robot framework.